# Calculate average from datagridview (column)

Tags: c#, datagridview, calculation

```
   public void Zoradanie(string mesiac)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ControlID.TextData))
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("sk-SK");
            var i = 0;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
                var datum = rows[0].Replace("\"", string.Empty);
              
                if (i >= 2 && datum[0] == mesiac[0] && datum[1] == mesiac[1])
                {                    
                    dr["Dátum"] = datum; 
                    dr["Teplota FV panelu"] = rows[49];
                    Dt.Rows.Add(dr);
               }
                 i++;
            }
           
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
        }
       
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);
        }

        double avg = sum / dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        string avgString = avg.ToString("N2"); 
        label1.Text = "The average is: " + avgString;

    }
```

Hi,
im trying to calcute average from numbers from Datagridview1, it take numbers automatically from .csv file and then i have ListCheckBox1 for sorting these datas by months. It works fine when i checked January, datagridview1 show only datas from January. This work fine. But now when i want add program to calculate average from numbers it write this error to me:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnCJu.png)

This is how it looks when i check January:
[how datagridview1 looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swwkG.jpg)

Could someone please help me solve my problem? Thank you

Comment: Data grids are good for viewing and editing data, but not good for data safety and calculations. You're best off loading your data into a strongly-typed list and working from there. Use the data grid to update the list and use the list to do your calculations.

Comment: Im totally beginner in programing, could you describe how to do that please ? I will appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect your month-matching logic (I think that's what `mesiac` refers to: unfortunately, I only speak English and French) may fail when you have months with more than 2 digits!

Comment: If any of these answers helped you, please consider making it as your accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Data grids are good for viewing and editing data, but not good for data safety and calculations. You're best off loading your data into a strongly-typed list and working from there. Use the data grid to update the list and use the list to do your calculations.

I've used an anonymous list in the code below, but you should get the idea.

```
public void Zoradanie(string mesiac)
{
    var data =
        from line in File.ReadLines(ControlID.TextData).Skip(2)
        let parts = line.Split(',')
        let datum = parts[0].Replace("\"", String.Empty)
        where datum.Substring(0, 2) == mesiac.Substring(0, 2)
        select new
        {
            datum,
            teplota_fv_panelu = double.Parse(parts[49]),
        };
        
    /* optional part to load data grid start */
    
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
        dr["Dátum"] = d.datum;
        dr["Teplota FV panelu"] = d.teplota_fv_panelu;
        Dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
    
    /* optional part to load data grid end */
    
    double avg = data.Average(x => x.teplota_fv_panelu);
    label1.Text = $"The average is: {avg.ToString("N2")}";
}
```

Comment: Very clean! I was thinking this would need to be more complicated than you've made it, and use a defined custom type for Pavol's data. But I like what you've done, still using DataRows!

Comment: Bonus esteem points for use of LINQ for more than just reading from databases!

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors here.

Here's one:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);
        }
```

You are looping through the rows of dataGridView1 ... but, you are always referencing `Rows[1]`, not `Rows[i]`, so you're going to accumulate the value of `Cells[0].Value` over and over.

That's assuming `Cells[0].Value` is convertible to `double`, which it isn't.  It's the cell from the column labeled "Dátum", which is a `string`.

You almost certainly want `Cells[1].Value` instead.

But user *enigmativity* is right: there are definitely easier ways to do this. Since you've got this line:

```
dr["Teplota FV panelu"] = rows[49];
```

and are putting `dr` in `Dt` (which I infer is a `DataTable`), why not convert it from a string to a double value at that point?

```
dr["Teplota FV panelu"] = Convert.ToDouble(rows[49]);
```

Then you could do this, using **Linq**:

```
var avg = Dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(dr => (double) dr["Teplota FV panelu"])
            .Average();
```